# Передача данных в function

Tags: php, функции, php7

В общем, есть такой код:

```
$arr =["1","2","6"];
function test($a,$z)
{
$minus=$z[1]-$a;
return $minus;
}
echo test(2,$arr);
```

Возможно ли сделать что бы не всегда указывать на $arr? Типа так:

```
$arr =["1","2","6"];
function test($a)
{
$minus=$arr[1]-$a;
return $minus;
}

echo test(2);
```

Или как то по другом можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в теле функции объявить массив $arr глобальным:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 6];
echo test(2);

function test($a) {
    global $arr;
    return $arr[1] - $a;
}
```

Но это не считается хорошей практикой.

---

Если у вас PHP не ниже версии 7, то ещё можно объявить константу со структурой массива *(константы имеют глобальную область видимости)*:

```
const ARR = [1, 2, 6];
echo test(2);

function test($a) {
    return ARR[1] - $a;
}
```

---

Если версия с константами не подходит, можно формировать для передачи в функцию массив, добавляя в первый элемент то значение, с которым нужно работать в теле функции. А в теле функции - извлекать из массива этот первый элемент:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 6];
array_unshift($arr, 2);

echo test($arr);

function test($arr) {
    $a = array_shift($arr);
    return $arr[1] - $a;
}
```

---

Ну и ещё один из вариантов - создать ещё одну пользовательскую функцию, которая будет возвращать массив, и вызывать эту функцию в теле первой функции:

```
echo test(2);

function test($a) {
    return get_array()[1] - $a;
}

function get_array() {
    return [1, 2, 6];
}
```

Comment: У сожалению PHP Version 5.6.8
 А почему первый вариант считается не хорошим? в плане плохой работоспособности или уязвимости?

Comment: @user286318 в плане поддержки _(отладки)_ кода. Если код не большой, и не планируется его развитие, и вы в этом точно уверены, то используйте глобальные переменные. Ну а если код большой, то вы просто устанете в поисках решения, в случае какой-то логической ошибки, искать именно "ту" переменную.

Comment: @user286318 я обновил ответ с учётом вашей версии php. И ещё можно массив прямо в теле функции объявить :)

Comment: код небольшой, спасибо большой, выбрал вариант с глобалом, но так же понравился последний вариант, спасибо большое :)